# Is it allowed to win a game of cribbage with the single point from a "go"?

Tags: cribbage

When playing cribbage and you're at a score of 120, can you then win the game by playing the last card and getting 1 point for the "go"? I've seen people play where you're not allowed to win via the "go", but my personal feeling is that's not correct.

Answer (score 3):

Indeed, I've heard much the same.
Turns out, it is merely a "common" house-rule.
There's no mention of any such limitation in any of the [rules](http://www.cribbage.org/rules/rule1.asp#section7) I've been able to find, but some people definitely play that way.

It seems to me that in Crib (even more so than in many other games) it's important to know what the house rules are before you start.